# usage of multinomial assign javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, multinomial

It is possible to assign multinomial variable in javascript like

```
let a = 10;
let b = a = 2; // like this
console.log(`a - ${a}, b - ${b}`); // prints "a - 2, b -2"
```

However, I could not find which case this expression is useful.
Is there any good reference of this usage?
(If this expression does not have particular strengths, should I block this in lint?)

Comment: If you use this, you just need to be careful that `a` is declared beforehand, so `let b = c = 2;` would create a new `c` variable in the global scope if it wasn't declared before. So `c` wouldn't be scoped to the block you assigned it in (whereas `b` would). In strict mode (which includes modules and classes), it was also result in an error if `c` hadn't been already declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about this, that's why you can't find any reference for it.

When you write

```
let b = a = 2;
```

it's just an instance of the general syntax

```
let <variable> = <expression>;
```

The expression happens to be `a = 2` -- an assignment is an expression that has the side effect of setting the variable and returns the value that was assigned. It's effectively the same as

```
a = 2;
let b = a;
```

Notice that there's no declaration there for `a`. If you hadn't declared `a` on the previous line, it would be assigned as a global variable rather than being a local variable declared with `let` (assuming this code is inside a function). Only `b` is being declared.